# PacMan Ghost Movement

Tags: python, pygame

So I've been trying to recreate the [PacMan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pac-Man) Game, I have been stuck on how to approach the idea of the Ghosts moving around the maze, I've heard of A* and Dijkstra's Algorithms, but is there a simpler way to implement ghosts moving around the maze? Aside from figuring out the different modes they can go into, Frightened, Chase, and Scatter, I just want to be able to understand whats the best way to get them to move randomly in the maze with the wall detection function in place.

```
import pygame
import time
#import random
import pickle
import math

pygame.init()
pygame.mixer.init()
pygame.display.set_caption("Pac-Man")

# Sets the size of the screen via (WIDTH, HEIGHT)
SCREEN_WIDTH = 478
SCREEN_HEIGHT = 608
# Speed of Characters
SPEED = 1
# Frames per second, how fast the game runs
FPS = 50
# Colors (RED,GREEN,BLUE)
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
YELLOW = (255, 255, 0)
BLUE = (0, 0, 255)

# Sets the WIDTH and HEIGHT of the window
WINDOW = (SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT)
# Displays the screen
SCREEN = pygame.display.set_mode(WINDOW)
CLOCK = pygame.time.Clock()

PacManStartSurface = pygame.transform.scale(pygame.image.load 
                                           ("PacManStart.png"), (23, 23))
PacManStartSurface.convert()
PacManStartRect = PacManStartSurface.get_rect(topleft = 
                                             (((SCREEN_WIDTH - 25) // 2),
                                             (SCREEN_HEIGHT + 144) // 2))

PacManSurface = pygame.transform.scale(pygame.image.load 
                                      ("PacManRight.png"), (23, 23))
PacManSurface.convert()
PacManRect = PacManStartSurface.get_rect(topleft = 
                                        (((SCREEN_WIDTH - 125) // 2),
                                        (SCREEN_HEIGHT + 144) // 2))

CurrentSurface = PacManStartSurface
CurrentRect = PacManStartRect 

BackgroundSurface = pygame.image.load("Background.png").convert()

PinkGhostSurface = pygame.transform.scale(pygame.image.load("PinkGhost.png")
                                           .convert(), (23, 23))
PinkGhostRect = PinkGhostSurface.get_rect()
YellowGhostSurface = pygame.transform.scale(pygame.image.load
                                           ("YellowGhost.png")
                                           .convert(), (23, 23))
YellowGhostRect = YellowGhostSurface.get_rect()
RedGhostSurface = pygame.transform.scale(pygame.image.load("RedGhost.png")
                                         .convert(), (23, 23))
RedGhostRect = RedGhostSurface.get_rect()
BlueGhostSurface = pygame.transform.scale(pygame.image.load("BlueGhost.png")
                                          .convert(), (23, 23))
BlueGhostRect = BlueGhostSurface.get_rect()

pygame.mixer.music.load('power_pellet.wav')

Font = pygame.font.Font("emulogic.ttf", 15)

class PacMan():
    def __init__(self):
        self.LIVES = 3
        
class Maze():
    def __init__(self):
        self.DOTS = []
        self.WALLS = []
        self.ENERGIZER = []
        self.GHOSTS = []
        self.DECISION_NODES = []
        self.BLOCK_WIDTH = 25
        self.BLOCK_HEIGHT = 25
        self.MAZE_OFFSET_X = 0
        self.MAZE_OFFSET_Y = 50
        self.MARGIN = 3
        # 0 - Dots
        # 1 - Walls
        # 2 - Energizers
        # 3 - Empty Spaces
        # 4 - Ghosts
        # 5 - Decision Nodes & will be added for intersections in maze
        self.MATRIX = [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1], \
                      [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1], \
                      [1,2,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,2,1], \
                      [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1], \
                      [1,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,0,1], \
                      [1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1], \
                      [1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,3,1,3,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1], \
                      [3,3,3,1,0,1,3,3,5,4,5,3,3,1,0,1,3,3,3], \
                      [1,1,1,1,0,1,3,1,1,1,1,1,3,1,0,1,1,1,1], \
                      [0,0,0,0,0,3,5,1,4,4,4,1,5,3,0,0,0,0,0], \
                      [1,1,1,1,0,1,3,1,1,1,1,1,3,1,0,1,1,1,1], \
                      [3,3,3,1,0,1,5,3,3,3,3,3,5,1,0,1,3,3,3], \
                      [1,1,1,1,0,1,3,1,1,1,1,1,3,1,0,1,1,1,1], \
                      [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1], \
                      [1,2,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,2,1], \
                      [1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,3,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1], \
                      [1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1], \
                      [1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1], \
                      [1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1], \
                      [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1], \
                      [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]
                      
        # BackgroundImage(X, Y, WIDTH, HEIGHT)
        self.MAZE_X = self.BLOCK_WIDTH * (len(self.MATRIX[0]) 
                      + self.MAZE_OFFSET_X)
        self.MAZE_Y = self.BLOCK_HEIGHT * (len(self.MATRIX)
                      + self.MAZE_OFFSET_Y)
        self.MAZE_WIDTH = self.BLOCK_WIDTH * len(self.MATRIX[0])
        self.MAZE_HEIGHT = self.BLOCK_HEIGHT * len(self.MATRIX) 

    def DrawMaze(self, MazeSurface):
        for ROW in range(len(self.MATRIX)):
            for COLUMN in range(len(self.MATRIX[0])):
                # Only saves the position of each dot
                if self.MATRIX[ROW][COLUMN] == 0:
                    self.DOTS.append([(self.BLOCK_WIDTH * COLUMN),
                                    (self.BLOCK_HEIGHT * ROW), 4, 4])
                if self.MATRIX[ROW][COLUMN] == 1:
                    self.WALLS.append(pygame.draw.rect(MazeSurface, WHITE,
                                     [((self.BLOCK_WIDTH) * COLUMN),
                                     ((self.BLOCK_HEIGHT) * ROW), 
                                     self.BLOCK_WIDTH, self.BLOCK_HEIGHT]))
                if self.MATRIX[ROW][COLUMN] == 2:
                    self.ENERGIZER.append([(self.BLOCK_WIDTH * COLUMN),
                                         (self.BLOCK_HEIGHT * ROW), 14, 14])
                if self.MATRIX[ROW][COLUMN] == 4:
                    self.GHOSTS.append([(self.BLOCK_WIDTH * COLUMN), 
                                      (self.BLOCK_HEIGHT * ROW), 23, 23])
                if self.MATRIX[ROW][COLUMN] == 5:
                    self.DECISION_NODES.append([(self.BLOCK_WIDTH * COLUMN), 
                                              (self.BLOCK_HEIGHT * ROW), 4, 4])  
         
class Main(Maze):
    def __init__(self):
        # Inherits Maze class
        Maze.__init__(self)
        self.TimeBetweenBites = 0.1
        self.LastBiteTime = time.time()
        self.MouthOpen = False
        self.PacManDirection = ""
        self.GhostDirection = ""
        self.PreviousGhostDirection = ""
        self.SCORE = 0
        self.HIGH_SCORE = 0
        
    def PacManMovement(self):
        key = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if key[pygame.K_LEFT] and not key[pygame.K_UP] \
                              and not key[pygame.K_DOWN]:
            self.PacManDirection = "LEFT"
        elif key[pygame.K_RIGHT] and not key[pygame.K_UP] \
                               and not key[pygame.K_DOWN]:
            self.PacManDirection = "RIGHT"
        elif key[pygame.K_UP] and not key[pygame.K_LEFT] \
                            and not key[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
            self.PacManDirection = "UP"
        elif key[pygame.K_DOWN] and not key[pygame.K_LEFT] \
                              and not key[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
            self.PacManDirection = "DOWN"
        
    def ContinuePacManMovement(self):
        if self.PacManDirection == "LEFT":
            CurrentRect.x -= SPEED
            self.PacManWallDetection(-1, 0, CurrentRect)
        if self.PacManDirection == "RIGHT":
            CurrentRect.x += SPEED
            self.PacManWallDetection(1, 0, CurrentRect)
        if self.PacManDirection == "UP":
            CurrentRect.y -= SPEED
            self.PacManWallDetection(0, -1, CurrentRect)
        if self.PacManDirection == "DOWN":
            CurrentRect.y += SPEED
            self.PacManWallDetection(0, 1, CurrentRect)
            
    def PacManTeleport(self):
        if CurrentRect.right < 0:
            CurrentRect.right = SCREEN_WIDTH + 20
        if CurrentRect.left > SCREEN_WIDTH:
            CurrentRect.right = 0
    
    def GhostTeleport(self):
        if PinkGhostRect.right < 0:
            PinkGhostRect.right = SCREEN_WIDTH + 20
        if PinkGhostRect.left > SCREEN_WIDTH:
            PinkGhostRect.right = 0
            
    def PacManWallDetection(self, x, y, CurrentRect):
        CurrentRect.right += x
        for WALL in self.WALLS:
            COLLIDE = CurrentRect.colliderect(WALL)
            if COLLIDE:
                if x < 0: 
                    CurrentRect.left = WALL.right
                    CurrentSurface = pygame.transform.rotate(PacManSurface, 180)
                    MazeSurface.blit(CurrentSurface, CurrentRect)
                if x > 0:
                    CurrentRect.right = WALL.left
                break
        
        CurrentRect.top += y
        for WALL in self.WALLS:
            COLLIDE = CurrentRect.colliderect(WALL)
            if COLLIDE:
                if y < 0:
                    CurrentRect.top = WALL.bottom
                if y > 0:
                    CurrentRect.bottom = WALL.top
                break
            
    def GhostWallDetection(self, x, y, PinkGhostRect):
        PinkGhostRect.right += x
        for WALL in self.WALLS:
            COLLIDE = PinkGhostRect.colliderect(WALL)
            if COLLIDE:
                if x < 0:
                    PinkGhostRect.left = WALL.right
                if x > 0:
                    PinkGhostRect.right = WALL.left
                break
        
        PinkGhostRect.top += y
        for WALL in self.WALLS:
            COLLIDE = PinkGhostRect.colliderect(WALL)
            if COLLIDE:
                if y < 0:
                    PinkGhostRect.top = WALL.bottom
                if y > 0:
                    PinkGhostRect.bottom = WALL.top 
                break
            
    def EatDots(self):
        for ROW in range(len(self.MATRIX)):
            for COLUMN in range(len(self.MATRIX[0])):
                for DOT in self.DOTS:
                    CHOMP = CurrentRect.colliderect(DOT)
                    if CHOMP:
                        Main.PlaySound(self, 0)
                        self.DOTS.remove(DOT)
                        self.MATRIX[ROW][COLUMN] = 3
                        self.SCORE += 10
        if self.SCORE > self.HIGH_SCORE:
            self.HIGH_SCORE = self.SCORE
        return str(self.SCORE), str(self.HIGH_SCORE)
    
    def EatEnergizer(self):
        for ROW in range(len(self.MATRIX)):
            for COLUMN in range(len(self.MATRIX[0])):
                for POWERUP in self.ENERGIZER:
                    CHOMP = CurrentRect.colliderect(POWERUP)
                    if CHOMP:
                        self.ENERGIZER.remove(POWERUP)
                        self.MATRIX[ROW][COLUMN] = 3
                        self.SCORE += 50
                        Main.PlaySound(self, 1)
        if self.SCORE > self.HIGH_SCORE:
            self.HIGH_SCORE = self.SCORE
        return str(self.SCORE), str(self.HIGH_SCORE)
    
    def EatGhosts(self):
        pass
                
    def DrawDots(self):
        for POSITION in self.DOTS:
            X = POSITION[0] + 13
            Y = POSITION[1] + 13
            WIDTH = POSITION[2]
            HEIGHT = POSITION[3]
            pygame.draw.circle(MazeSurface, YELLOW, (X, Y), 
                               WIDTH // 2, HEIGHT // 2)
            
    def DrawEnergizer(self):
        for POSITION in self.ENERGIZER:
            X = POSITION[0] + 13
            Y = POSITION[1] + 13
            WIDTH = POSITION[2] 
            HEIGHT = POSITION[3] 
            pygame.draw.circle(MazeSurface, YELLOW, (X, Y), 
                               WIDTH // 2, HEIGHT // 2)

    def DrawGhosts(self):        
        MazeSurface.blit(PinkGhostSurface, PinkGhostRect) 
        MazeSurface.blit(YellowGhostSurface, YellowGhostRect) 
        MazeSurface.blit(RedGhostSurface, RedGhostRect) 
        MazeSurface.blit(BlueGhostSurface, BlueGhostRect) 
        
    def GhostPosition(self):
        X, Y, WIDTH, HEIGHT = self.GHOSTS[0]
        PinkGhostRect.x = X
        PinkGhostRect.y = Y
        PinkGhostRect.width = WIDTH
        PinkGhostRect.height = HEIGHT
        
        X, Y, WIDTH, HEIGHT = self.GHOSTS[1]
        YellowGhostRect.x = X
        YellowGhostRect.y = Y
        YellowGhostRect.width = WIDTH
        YellowGhostRect.height = HEIGHT
        
        X, Y, WIDTH, HEIGHT = self.GHOSTS[2]
        RedGhostRect.x = X
        RedGhostRect.y = Y
        RedGhostRect.width = WIDTH
        RedGhostRect.height = HEIGHT
        
        X, Y, WIDTH, HEIGHT = self.GHOSTS[3]
        BlueGhostRect.x = X
        BlueGhostRect.y = Y
        BlueGhostRect.width = WIDTH
        BlueGhostRect.height = HEIGHT
    
    def ChaseMode(self):
        self.GhostDirection = "LEFT"
        self.GhostWallDetection(-1, 0, PinkGhostRect)
        if PinkGhostRect.x < CurrentRect.x:
            self.GhostDirection = "RIGHT"
            self.GhostWallDetection(1, 0, PinkGhostRect)
        if PinkGhostRect.y > CurrentRect.y:
            self.GhostDirection = "UP"
            self.GhostWallDetection(0, -1, PinkGhostRect)
        if PinkGhostRect.y < CurrentRect.y:
            self.GhostDirection = "DOWN"
            self.GhostWallDetection(0, 1, PinkGhostRect)
    
    def ScatterMode(self):
        pass
    
    def FrightenedMode(self):
        pass
        
    def PlaySound(self, Track):
        if Track == 0:
            Eat = pygame.mixer.Sound("pacman_chomp.wav")
            Eat.play()
            pygame.mixer.fadeout(400)
        if Track == 1:
            EatPellet = pygame.mixer.Sound("pacman_eatghost.wav")
            EatPellet.play()
            pygame.mixer.music.play(7)
            pygame.mixer.fadeout(400)
                
    def ShowScore(self):
        global Font
        OneUpText = Font.render("1UP", True, WHITE)
        OneUpTextRect = OneUpText.get_rect(center = (70, 10))
        # Displays current score
        OneUpScoreText = Font.render(str(self.SCORE), True, WHITE)
        OneUpScoreRect = OneUpScoreText.get_rect(center =
                                                ((SCREEN_WIDTH - 290) 
                                                // 2, 26))
        HighScoreText = Font.render("High Score", True, WHITE)
        HighScoreTextRect = HighScoreText.get_rect(center = 
                                                  (SCREEN_WIDTH // 2, 10))
        # Displays High Score
        HighScoreNumber = Font.render(str(self.HIGH_SCORE), True, WHITE)
        HighScoreNumberRect = HighScoreNumber.get_rect(center = 
                                                      ((SCREEN_WIDTH + 90) 
                                                      // 2, 26))
        SCREEN.blit(OneUpText, OneUpTextRect)
        SCREEN.blit(OneUpScoreText, OneUpScoreRect)
        SCREEN.blit(HighScoreText, HighScoreTextRect)
        SCREEN.blit(HighScoreNumber, HighScoreNumberRect)
        
    def PacManBite(self):
        global CurrentSurface
        CurrentTime = time.time()
        if CurrentTime - self.LastBiteTime >= self.TimeBetweenBites:
            self.LastBiteTime = CurrentTime
            if self.MouthOpen:
                CurrentSurface = PacManStartSurface
            else:
                CurrentSurface = PacManSurface
            self.MouthOpen = not self.MouthOpen
            if self.PacManDirection == "LEFT":
                CurrentSurface = pygame.transform.rotate(CurrentSurface, 180)
            if self.PacManDirection == "RIGHT":
                CurrentSurface = CurrentSurface
            if self.PacManDirection == "UP":
                CurrentSurface = pygame.transform.rotate(CurrentSurface, 90)
            if self.PacManDirection == "DOWN":
                CurrentSurface = pygame.transform.rotate(CurrentSurface, 270)
    
    def PacManLives(self):
        pass
        
Player = Main()

BackgroundSurface = pygame.transform.scale(BackgroundSurface, 
                                          (Player.MAZE_WIDTH, 
                                           Player.MAZE_HEIGHT))
BackgroundRect = BackgroundSurface.get_rect()

MazeSurface = pygame.Surface((Player.MAZE_WIDTH, Player.MAZE_HEIGHT))
MazeRect = MazeSurface.get_rect(topleft = (Player.MAZE_OFFSET_X, 
                                           Player.MAZE_OFFSET_Y))
Player.DrawMaze(MazeSurface)
Player.GhostPosition()
#Player.GhostMovement()

'''
Before the game starts ...
pregame = True
while pregame:
    if key button pressed:
        pregame = False
    run = True
'''

run = True
while run:
    SCREEN.fill(BLACK)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            Player.PacManMovement()
            Player.PacManTeleport()   
            
    Player.ContinuePacManMovement()
    MazeSurface.blit(BackgroundSurface, BackgroundRect) 
    Player.DrawDots()
    Player.DrawEnergizer()
    Player.DrawGhosts()
    Player.GhostTeleport()
    Player.EatDots()
    Player.EatEnergizer()
    Player.ChaseMode()
    MazeSurface.blit(CurrentSurface, CurrentRect)
    Player.PacManBite()
    SCREEN.blit(MazeSurface, MazeRect)
    Player.ShowScore()
    pygame.display.update()
    CLOCK.tick(FPS)
    
pygame.quit()
```

Comment: The AI of the original PacMan was nowhere near as complicated as A* or Dijkstra's - they simply moved in the direction of PacMan whenever they reached an intersection and always kept moving forward (i.e. not back-tracking, unless in a dead end)

Comment: You'd probably be interested in [this](https://stanford.edu/~cpiech/cs221/homework/prog/pacman/pacman.html)

Comment: From Wikipedia:  Each of the four ghosts has their own unique artificial intelligence (A.I.), or "personality": Blinky gives direct chase to Pac-Man; Pinky and Inky try to position themselves in front of Pac-Man, usually by cornering him; and Clyde will switch between chasing Pac-Man and fleeing from him.

Answer (score 0):

An easy algorithm for moving is simply looking at the available exits from *this* position and choose where to go.

Watching Pacman for a few minutes leads to a few movement rules:

- The direction is only changed on exact map-grid boundaries (true for all entities).
- Ghosts do not stop
- Ghosts do not reverse direction
- ... unless becoming edible (out of scope for now)

So I implemented this in a simple heuristic:

- Unless in a dead-end, do not reverse
- Always move forward, but if we can turn, still prefer forward (60% of the time)

To code this, the `GhostSprite` simply remembers its current direction in `self.direction`, which is a compass bearing `N`orth, `E`ast, `S`outh, `W`est.  North is toward the top of the window (`-Y`), West to the left (`-X`).

This makes the Ghost's direction control reduce down to a single algorithm:

- By consulting the map, list the available exits
- Is the only available direction in reverse?

  - Yes: turn around
  - No:

    - 60% of the time continue forward
    - 40% of the time, choose a random direction for what's available

In my implementation the ghosts jump whole grid co-ordinates.  In versions with per-pixel movement, the ghost needs only check that it on an exact grid-boundary before bothering to check for direction changes.  Something like a `self.rect.x % GRID_SIZE == 0` would achieve that quickly.

[image: pacman_algorithm]

** Code **

```
import pygame
import random

# Window size
WINDOW_WIDTH      = 420
WINDOW_HEIGHT     = 465

GRID_SIZE = WINDOW_HEIGHT // 21

MAP_WIDTH  = 19
MAP_HEIGHT = 21
MAP = [ "###################", 
        "#        #        #",
        "# ## ### # ### ## #",
        "#                 #",
        "# ## # ##### # ## #",
        "#    #   #   #    #",
        "#### ### # ### ####",
        "#### #       # ####",
        "#### # ## ## # ####",
        "<      #   #      >",
        "#### # ##### # ####",
        "#### #   c   # ####",
        "#### # ##### # ####",
        "#        #        #",
        "# ## ### # ### ## #",
        "#  #           #  #",
        "## # # ##### # # ##",
        "#    #   #   #    #",
        "# ###### # ###### #",
        "#                 #",
        "###################" ]

BLACK    = (  0,   0,   0)
YELLOW   = (255, 255,   0)
BLUE     = (  0,   0, 254)
RED      = (255,   0,   0)
LIGHTBLUE= (161, 255, 254)
PINK     = (255, 192, 203)
ORANGE   = (255, 165,   0)


def pixelPosToGridPos( pixel_x, pixel_y ):
    """ Map a window-pixel position to a map-grid position """
    return ( pixel_x // GRID_SIZE, pixel_y // GRID_SIZE )

def gridPosToPixelPos( grid_x, grid_y ):
    """ Map a grid position to a window-position position """
    return ( grid_x * GRID_SIZE, grid_y * GRID_SIZE )
    
def getMapColour( x, y ):
    """ Convert map symbols into colours """
    symbol = MAP[y][x]
    if ( symbol == '#' ):
        return BLUE
    elif ( symbol == 'c' ):
        return YELLOW
    elif ( symbol == 'b' ):   # "Shadow" / "Blinky"
        return RED
    elif ( symbol == 'p' ):   # "Speedy" / "Pinky"
        return PINK
    elif ( symbol == 'i' ):   # "Bashful" / "Inky"
        return LIGHTBLUE
    elif ( symbol == 'o' ):   # "Pokey" / "Clyde"
        return ORANGE
    return BLACK


class GhostSprite( pygame.sprite.Sprite ):
    """ A pacman-like ghost sprite """

    def __init__( self, grid_x, grid_y, colour ):
        super().__init__()
        self.image = pygame.Surface( ( GRID_SIZE, GRID_SIZE), pygame.SRCALPHA )
        self.image.fill( colour )
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.topleft = gridPosToPixelPos( grid_x, grid_y )
        self.direction = random.choice( [ 'N', 'S', 'E', 'W' ] ) 


    def moveToGrid( self, grid_x, grid_y ):
        """ Allow position to be reset """
        self.rect.topleft = gridPosToPixelPos( grid_x, grid_y )

    def availableMoves( self ):
        """ Consult the map to see where is good to go from here.
            We only consider walls, not other NPCs """
        map_x, map_y = pixelPosToGridPos( self.rect.x, self.rect.y )
        exits = []
        # handle wrap-around, where it's possible to go "off grid"
        if ( map_x <= 0 or map_x >= MAP_WIDTH-1 ):
            exits = [ 'E', 'W' ]
        else:
            # otherwise consult the map
            if ( MAP[ map_y-1 ][ map_x ] != '#' ):
                exits.append( 'N' )
            if ( MAP[ map_y ][ map_x+1 ] != '#' ):
                exits.append( 'E' )
            if ( MAP[ map_y+1 ][ map_x ] != '#' ):
                exits.append( 'S' )
            if ( MAP[ map_y ][ map_x-1 ] != '#' ):
                exits.append( 'W' )
        return exits

    def getOppositeDirection( self ):
        """ Return the compass-opposite of our current movement direction """
        opposites = { 'N':'S', 'S':'N', 'E':'W', 'W':'E' };
        return opposites[ self.direction ]

    def moveForward( self ):
        """ Move in the current direction.  Generally we use the map
            to keep us in-bounds, but on the wrap-around we can get
            close to the edge of the map, so use special handling for
            warping """
        # handle wrap-around avenue
        map_x, map_y = pixelPosToGridPos( self.rect.x, self.rect.y )
        if ( MAP[ map_y ][ map_x ] == '<' ):
            self.direction = 'W'
            self.rect.x = (MAP_WIDTH-1) * GRID_SIZE
        elif ( MAP[ map_y ][ map_x ] == '>' ):
            self.direction = 'E'
            self.rect.x = 0
            
        # Whichever direction we're moving in, go forward
        if ( self.direction == 'N' ):
            self.rect.y -= GRID_SIZE
        elif ( self.direction == 'E' ):
            self.rect.x += GRID_SIZE
        elif ( self.direction == 'S' ):
            self.rect.y += GRID_SIZE
        else:  # W
            self.rect.x -= GRID_SIZE


    def update( self ):
        """ Move the ghost, mostly forward, never backwards (unless dead-end)
            At an intersection, possibly turn """
        exits = self.availableMoves()
        # Generally: Keep moving in current direction, never u-turn 
        opposite = self.getOppositeDirection()
        # 60% change of continuing forward at an intersection
        if ( self.direction in exits and ( len( exits ) == 1 or random.randrange( 0,100 ) <= 60 ) ):
            pass
        elif ( self.direction not in exits and len( exits ) == 1 ):
            self.direction = exits[0]   # maybe u-turn
        else:  # more than 1 exit
            if ( opposite in exits ):
                exits.remove( opposite )
            self.direction = random.choice( exits )
        # Move-it- Move-it
        self.moveForward()



###
### MAIN
###
pygame.init()
window  = pygame.display.set_mode( ( WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT ), pygame.HWSURFACE )
pygame.display.set_caption("Pac Algorithm")

# Make background image of map
background = pygame.Surface( ( WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT ), pygame.SRCALPHA )
for y in range( MAP_HEIGHT ):
    for x in range( MAP_WIDTH ):
        rect = pygame.Rect( x * GRID_SIZE, y * GRID_SIZE, GRID_SIZE, GRID_SIZE )
        pygame.draw.rect( background, getMapColour( x, y ), rect )

# Make the Ghosts
blinky = GhostSprite( 9, 7, RED )
inky   = GhostSprite( 8, 9, LIGHTBLUE )
pinky  = GhostSprite( 9, 9, PINK )
pokey  = GhostSprite(10, 9, ORANGE )
ghosts = pygame.sprite.Group() 
ghosts.add( [ blinky, inky, pinky, pokey ] )

# Ghosts move periodically
next_ghost_movement = pygame.time.get_ticks() + 1000

# Main loop
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
running = True
while running:
    time_now = pygame.time.get_ticks()
    # Handle user-input
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if ( event.type == pygame.QUIT ):
            running = False

    # Movement keys
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if ( keys[pygame.K_UP] ):
        print("up")
    elif ( keys[pygame.K_DOWN] ):
        print("down")
    elif ( keys[pygame.K_LEFT] ):
        print("left")
    elif ( keys[pygame.K_RIGHT] ):
        print("right")
    elif ( keys[pygame.K_ESCAPE] ):
        # Reset the ghosts home
        blinky.moveToGrid( 9, 7 )
        inky.moveToGrid( 8, 9 )
        pinky.moveToGrid( 9, 9 )
        pokey.moveToGrid( 10, 9 )
        next_ghost_movement = time_now + 1000 

    # move the ghosts
    if ( time_now > next_ghost_movement ):
        ghosts.update()
        next_ghost_movement = time_now + 100 

    # Update the window, but not more than 60fps
    window.blit( background, ( 0, 0 ) )
    ghosts.draw( window )
    pygame.display.flip()

    # Clamp FPS
    clock.tick(30)

pygame.quit()
```

Comment: Im trying to understand your logic, I tried to come up with a way so that the ghosts move every frame, and grabbed its coordinates to decide the next available coordinates, so I have a function that gets the current location of the ghost and I used [(-1,0),(1,0),(0,-1),(0,1)] to see what its options are, if the next y or x coordinate is a 1(meaning I mapping it back to the maze) then don't add it to a list of possibilities because its a wall, otherwise choose randomnly where to move to next, so far I can't get them to move

Comment: @EdwinNavar - Are you checking the "map" co-ordinates, or window co-ordinates?  In my example I use the map as the reference about where turns can be made.  But first you need to  ensure your ghost is on an exact map-cell (not moving between 2 cells).  if it's not on an exact cell, it should just keep moving forward.

Comment: Yeah I mapped it to the coordinates on my maze, It's weird how Im approaching it, I just check for the neighbors on every move, and Im trying to implement it to move forward majority of the time, if it hits a dead end, only then can it reverse

Comment: Based off my code, do you know how I would be able to map the current position to map position?

Comment: in your case, why are you using 21 to divide to get the GridSize? I am trying to figure out how to map random coordinates, (these are just random coordinates), for example (239, 175) to (8,0) on the matrix i have.

Comment: Looking at your code, I think your pacman is on an exact cell when `CurrentRect.y % SCREEN_HEIGHT == 0 and CurrentRect.x % SCREEN_WIDTH == 0`.  It might help streamline your code to move some of these stats in the `PacMan` class.  I chose 21 for the grid size just as an easy value to give a small window for the animated .gif (which has a limited upload-size).  Probably I should have made the window's size a multiple of grid-size, that would have worked out nicer.

Comment: I got it working, all Im doing is checking if the current position is % 25 == 0 meaning its within a block cell, if it is, then grab the available moves and repeat

Comment: as far as the wrap around feature, whenever Im going left and the ghost is out of the screen, is there a way to map it back to the right side of the maze?

Comment: @EdwinNavar - You can test the X-position, because it's *only* when going through the "tunnel" that the X value can be zero (or even less than the width of the maze border) on the left-side. On the right-side, greater-than/equal-to window-width. So it's quite easy to test, see the 6th line of `GhostSprite.availableMoves()`.  If the ghost moves off the screen, just wrap it to the other side.

Comment: Nevermind I fixed it, just had to check the position(s) before it goes off grid, so that I can stop searching for next available move, so it can go off screen and continue in that direction when it appears again